# Merging audio files in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I was found multiple code examples to concatenate audio files with one file, as in this example: 
[How to concat 2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18743678/2519297)

But the problem is each audio file has header(meta data), so when merging the files the result file has total size of files(so the concatenate is correct), but when play the result file only first file is running.

Any one can help me in this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Well an audio file is composed by a Header and a Content. The Header says (among the other things) how much the Content is long. What you are doing is to attach 2 files. So what you get is `Header1, Content1, Header2, Content2`. But Header1 tells the media player (whichever it is) to **stop after Content1**.

Comment: In practice, you are just doing `cat file1 file2 > file3`

Comment: okay thanks for your comments, but I understand this information .. could you help me by simple code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two or more .wav files in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452464/merging-two-or-more-wav-files-in-android)

Comment: Finally, I found a great example in this article:
[AudioRecord_Player](http://www.pastie.org/2165869#6,10,16,21,55,57,59,63,70,81,94,173,198-199,203)

Comment: I was seeing this answer, but unfortunately it's not helping me.